# What's the best way to add a drop shadow to my UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, shadow, cliptobounds

I am trying to add a drop shadow to views that are layered on top of one another, the views collapse allowing content in other views to be seen, in this vein i want to keep `view.clipsToBounds` ON so that when the views collapse their content is clipped.

This seems to have made it difficult for me to add a drop shadow to the layers as when i turn `clipsToBounds` ON the shadows are clipped also.

I have been trying to manipulate `view.frame` and `view.bounds` in order to add a drop shadow to the frame but allow the bounds to be large enough to encompass it, however I have had no luck with this.

Here is the code I am using to add a Shadow (this only works with `clipsToBounds` OFF as shown)

```
view.clipsToBounds = NO;
view.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,5);
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
```

Here is a screenshot of the shadow being applied to the top lightest grey layer. Hopefully this gives an idea of how my content will overlap if `clipsToBounds` is OFF.

[image: Shadow Application.]

How can I add a shadow to my `UIView` and keep my content clipped?

Edit: Just wanted to add that I have also played around with using background images with shadows on, which does work well, however I would still like to know the best coded solution for this.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

Try this:

```
UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:view.bounds];
view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 5.0f);
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
view.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
```

**First of all**: The `UIBezierPath` used as `shadowPath` is crucial.  If you don't use it, you might not notice a difference at first, but the keen eye will observe a certain lag occurring during events like rotating the device and/or similar. It's an important performance tweak.

**Regarding your issue specifically**: The important line is `view.layer.masksToBounds = NO`. It disables the clipping of *the view's layer's sublayers* that extend further than the view's bounds.

For those wondering what the difference between `masksToBounds` (on the layer) and the view's own `clipToBounds` property is: There isn't really any. Toggling one will have an effect on the other. Just a different level of abstraction.

---

Swift 2.2:

```
override func layoutSubviews()
{
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds)
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 5.0)
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath
}
```

---

Swift 3:

```
override func layoutSubviews()
{
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds)
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 5.0)
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code and then tried adding `masksToBounds = NO;` to my original - with both attempts i kept `clipsToBounds = YES;` ON - both failed to clip the content. heres a screencap of what happend with your example > http://youtu.be/tdpemc_Xdps

Comment: Any ideas on how to get the drop shadow to hug a rounded corner rather than rendering as if the corner is still a square?

Comment: @JohnErck try this: `UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds cornerRadius:5.0];`. Not tested but should yield the result you want.

Comment: I have learned that when animating the view, the shadow leaves gray tracks while moving. Removing the shadowPath lines solved this

Comment: why does this have to be done in `layoutSubviews()`? -- i'm finding that this code only works when executed inside it

Comment: @shoe because any time size of the view changes, `layoutSubviews()` is called. And if we don't compensate in that place by adjusting the `shadowPath` to reflect the current size, we'd have a resized view but the shadow would still be the old (initial) size and either not show or peek out where it shouldn't.

Comment: @pkluz but my view's size doesn't change, only it's position

Comment: @shoe `layoutSubviews()` is still called. Also remember that views when they are initialized don't immediately start with the right size. So if you were to apply the `shadowPath` right after `init`, you're not guaranteed to have the right sizing yet. `layoutSubviews()` guarantees that you can respond to any change. And that includes responding to position changes too. (Think about directional shadows... - you could implement this too)

Answer (score 66):

Wasabii's answer in Swift 2.3:

```
let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds)
view.layer.masksToBounds = false
view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0.5)
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
view.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath
```

And in Swift 3/4/5:

```
let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds)
view.layer.masksToBounds = false
view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0.5)
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
view.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
```

Put this code in layoutSubviews() if you're using AutoLayout.

In SwiftUI, this is all much easier:

```
Color.yellow  // or whatever your view
    .shadow(radius: 3)
    .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
```

Comment: Thanks for noting `layoutSubviews`

Comment: or even better in viewDidLayoutSubviews()

Comment: prefer swift struct initialisers over Make variants, i.e. `CGSize(width: 0, height: 0.5)`

Comment: I add this code to layoutSubviews(), it still didnt render in IB. Are there other settings i have to opt in?

Comment: Thanks. I was using Auto Layout and I thought to my self - well.. `view.bounds` has not been created so obviously that `shadowPath` can't reference the view's rect but some `CGRectZero` instead. 
Anyway, putting this under `layoutSubviews` solved my problem at last!

Comment: @Bart va Kuil Thank you for `layoutSubviews ` hint!

Answer (score 13):

The trick is defining the `masksToBounds` property of your view's layer properly:

```
view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

and it should work.

([Source](http://labs.freescapes.org/blog/2011/08/how-to-give-uiwebview-rounded-corners-and-a-shadow/))

Answer (score 13):

You can create an extension for UIView to access these values in the design editor

[image: Shadow options in design editor]

```
extension UIView{

    @IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGSize{
        get{
            return self.layer.shadowOffset
        }
        set{
            self.layer.shadowOffset = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor{
        get{
            return UIColor(cgColor: self.layer.shadowColor!)
        }
        set{
            self.layer.shadowColor = newValue.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat{
        get{
            return self.layer.shadowRadius
        }
        set{
            self.layer.shadowRadius = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float{
        get{
            return self.layer.shadowOpacity
        }
        set{
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to refer to that extension in interface builder

Comment: IBInspectable makes it available in the interface builder

Comment: Can I achieve this in Objective C too ?

Comment: if you want to have a real-time preview (in interface builder), here you can find a good article about it   https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/07/18/swift-interface-builder/

Answer (score 8):

You can set shadow to your view from storyboard also

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On viewWillLayoutSubviews:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    sampleView.layer.masksToBounds =  false
    sampleView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor;
    sampleView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)
    sampleView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
}
```

Using Extension of UIView:

```
extension UIView {

    func addDropShadowToView(targetView:UIView? ){
        targetView!.layer.masksToBounds =  false
        targetView!.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor;
        targetView!.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)
        targetView!.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
sampleView.addDropShadowToView(sampleView)
```

Comment: Just enforce `targetView: UIView` and remove the bangs.

Comment: Why not use `self`? Seems much more convenient to me.

Comment: A better way to do this is to remove targetView as a parameter and use self instead of targetView. This eliminates redundancy and allows one to call it like so: sampleView.addDropShadowToView()

Comment: Max Nelson's comment are great.  My suggestion is use `if let` syntax instead of `!`

Answer (score 0):

So yes, you should prefer the shadowPath property for performance, but also:
From the header file of CALayer.shadowPath

Specifying the path explicitly using this property will usually
     * improve rendering performance, as will sharing the same path
     * reference across multiple layers

A lesser known trick is sharing the same reference across multiple layers. Of course they have to use the same shape, but this is common with table/collection view cells.

I don't know why it gets faster if you share instances, i'm guessing it caches the rendering of the shadow and can reuse it for other instances in the view. I wonder if this is even faster with