# Shadow gets cut by superview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, shadow

I tried to apply a shadow to an uiView inside a containerView. The problem is that the shadow at the top gets cut by the boundaries of the containerView. Here you can see my view hierarchy:

```
> containerView
    > pageViewController
        > scrollView
            > view
                > view !!! → the shadow was here applied
```

It looks like this:

[image: cutted shadow by the containerView]

I tried to apply layer.masksToBounds to several superViews of my "shadowView" but nothing helped...

Has anyone a solution?

Thank you in advance!

With best regards Tom

Comment: containerView.clipsToBounds = false

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shadow UIview and clipsToBounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760918/shadow-uiview-and-clipstobounds)

Comment: @Sneak I tried both, clipsToBounds = false and masksToBounds = false. Sadly nothing has changed...

Comment: You have a massive chain of views inside the containerView. You need to set every one of them to false. Otherwise somewhere in the chain, it wil get clipped. Same with your pageViewController.view