# Adding shadow to top of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

How can I add a shadow to the top of my `UIView` I've tried the following but with no luck...

```
childView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
childView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
childView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-15, 20);
childView.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
childView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
```

Comment: When you say "top", you mean "in front" or "above"? If you mean above, the `y` value on `CGSizeMake` should be negative.

Answer (score 28):

Swift 3 Extension:

This includes default values for the app I'm working on, but you can change them to match the style you want in your app.

```
enum VerticalLocation: String {
    case bottom
    case top  
}

extension UIView {
    func addShadow(location: VerticalLocation, color: UIColor = .black, opacity: Float = 0.5, radius: CGFloat = 5.0) {
        switch location {
        case .bottom:
             addShadow(offset: CGSize(width: 0, height: 10), color: color, opacity: opacity, radius: radius)
        case .top:
            addShadow(offset: CGSize(width: 0, height: -10), color: color, opacity: opacity, radius: radius)
        }
    }

    func addShadow(offset: CGSize, color: UIColor = .black, opacity: Float = 0.5, radius: CGFloat = 5.0) {
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = offset
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
        self.layer.shadowRadius = radius
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to add a shadow to all subviews

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the childview's `masksToBounds` property to `NO` in order to make the shadow visible.

```
childView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Comment: what if I want the view to also be rounded? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509547/uiview-with-rounded-corners

Answer (score 4):

1.Step: First create an outlet of uiview

2.Step:

```
    buttonBackgroundView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
    buttonBackgroundView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
    buttonBackgroundView.layer.shadowRadius = 15.0
    buttonBackgroundView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your `masksToBounds = NO`.  The reason you are not seeing the shadow is because it is completely hidden behind your view when the masksToBounds is YES.

If your button is rounded you can instead adjust the view's imageEdgeInset value. ie: `UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 0, 10);`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting masksToBounds to NO. According to this link [Whats the best way to add a drop shadow to my UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761189/whats-the-best-way-to-add-a-drop-shadow-to-my-uiview) making that YES will clip the layers extending past the view's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in `UIBezierPath`

You can find a really interesting article there:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/155/advanced-uiview-shadow-effects-using-shadowpath

```
layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -2)
layer.shadowRadius = 5
layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: -1,
                                             y: -1,
                                             width: self.bounds.width,
                                             height: self.layer.shadowRadius)).cgPath
```