# Swift - UIView with shadow different corner radiuses

Tags: swift, uiview

How to create an UIView with different corner radius? for example, one corner should have radius 5 and other three corners should have radius 20. And finally need to add shadow to the view.
 Here in sample facebook messenger chat bubble, one corner has small radius and other has different corner radius.
[Here the sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZm95.png)

Comment: As I flagged the question, I did not notice the second part of the question. However that as well has an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761189/whats-the-best-way-to-add-a-drop-shadow-to-my-uiview) on stack overflow.

Comment: I want different corner radius, like topLetf -> 10, topRight -> 15 , bottomLeft should have 12, bottomRight-> 20 ,but as per your suggestion we can't archive this.