# How to add shadow to an UIView in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios, shadow

I found this link for doing it in Swift:
[What's the best way to add a drop shadow to my UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761189/whats-the-best-way-to-add-a-drop-shadow-to-my-uiview/60037258#60037258)

However when I adapt the solution to Xamarin, no shadow appears.

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

    UIBezierPath path = new UIBezierPath();
    PreviousButton.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
    PreviousButton.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.Gray.CGColor;
    PreviousButton.Layer.ShadowOffset = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(0f, 7f);
    PreviousButton.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 1;
    PreviousButton.Layer.ShadowPath = path.CGPath;
}
```

I am using AutoLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**

You seem forgot to set the **Rect** of the path

**Solution 1:**

You could directly set the shadow of the button

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

    PreviousButton.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
    PreviousButton.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.Gray.CGColor;
    PreviousButton.Layer.ShadowOffset = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(0f, 7f);
    PreviousButton.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 1;   
}
```

**Solution 2:**
If you do want to use BezierPath , set the rect of it .

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();
    UIBezierPath path = UIBezierPath.FromRect(PreviousButton.Bounds);
    PreviousButton.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
    PreviousButton.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.Gray.CGColor;
    PreviousButton.Layer.ShadowOffset = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(0f, 7f);
    PreviousButton.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 1;
    PreviousButton.Layer.ShadowPath = path.CGPath;   
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now. Yes, I was missing the FromRect implementation.